# Add Decimal Point after First Digit in a Numeric Value

Tags: sql-server

Can any one here please advise how to add a decimal point after first digit while selecting numeric value from database?

> Example: Output is 8250 should be 8.250

I tried this:

`convert(decimal(10,3),ti.Rate/1000) AS Amount`

but the output returns the wrong value of `8.000`. It should be `8.250`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @value INT = 8250

PRINT convert(DECIMAL(10, 3), @value / 1000.00)
```

> 8.250

Answer (score 1):

Because all the values inside the convert call are integers it is performing integer division to get an integer result before converting to a decimal. `ti.Rate/1000` is 8250/1000 which with integer division becomes 8. `CONVERT` then changes the type but the extra precision is already lost.

If you add a decimal place to the numeric literal 1000, SQL Server will see it as a decimal/numeric type number instead of an integer, so all you need to do is `CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,3),ti.Rate/1000.0) AS Amount`. Dividing an integer by a decimal/numeric (or vice-versa) results in a decimal/numeric.

In fact you can probably just do `ti.Rate/1000.0 AS Amount` unless you specifically need the type to be exactly `DECIMAL(10,3)` instead of the default (a quick test on SQL2016 shows the default to be `NUMERIC(17,6)`, note that numeric and decimal are functionally identical as one is a synonym for the other). Or if you *do* specifically need `DECIMAL(10,3)`, you might avoid extra implicit conversions by converting one of the inputs instead of the output: `CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,3),ti.Rate)/1000.0 AS Amount` (though the performance difference here is likely to be at best infinitesimal).